# Can an abstract class be a subclass?

Tags: python, oop

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    @abstractmethod
    def something():
        pass
    
class B(A):
    pass
```

I'm still new to learning OOP so I would like to ask this. I know that an abstract class is considered a superclass, but can an abstract class be a subclass as well?

Using the code as an example, `B` inherits from `A` but does not override the abstract methods in `A`, so does this mean that `B` is still considered an abstract class as well as as a subclass of `A`?

Comment: I don’t know Python, but by straight OO principles, abstract classes can certainly be a subclass.  A great habit to get into is avoid “anaemic” meaningless names like A and B, but use actual names like Animal and Bird - and it becomes immediately obvious that Bird would be abstract (you might have have Eagles and Swans as subclasses).  Most languages also allow abstract sub-classes from concrete super-classes (though personally I dislike that)

Comment: The class in your question is a subclass - it's a subclass of `ABC`. If you didn't write `class A(ABC):` then it would be a subclass of `object` instead. So *every* class is a subclass, except `object` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what is an abstract class? It is a class that is to be used as a "skeleton" for a subclass.
Now to your question....

> So does this mean that B is still considered an abstract class as well as as a subclass of A?

Yes, because all of the methods are not overridden, and they are abstract.

Take this code for example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod    
class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return 'Foo implementation'
```

Here, the class `B` is still abstract since one of the methods is not overridden that is abstract. So if you try to create an instance of that, you'll get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods bar
```

Here we can see that this class inherits from `A`, but is a concrete class, since the methods are overridden:

```
class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

c = C()
c.foo()
```

This code runs without errors.

In short, a subclass of an abstract class is still an abstract class as long as the methods are not overridden.

Comment: What if C inherits from a class `B`, which overrides the abstract methods, but C itself does not override?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As long as you don't override all the abstract methods, the subclass is still abstract.